# simpleJDBCTemplate not replacing quoted parameter

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am using simpleJDBCTemplate to insert a value to a postgre database.

```
String sql "insert into testTable values(:bla, :blah, functionThatTakesAText(':blu'))"
BeanPropertySqlParameterSource namedParameters = new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(lighting);
simpleJdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameters);
```

Now, the blu parameter is actually a number(the actual sql takes 2 real's ) that is read from a file given by the client.

As a result the database receives something like the following:

```
insert into testTable values(?, ?, functionThatTakesAText(':blu'))
```

and fails to replace the :blu parameter as expected.

The current workaround that I'm using is replacing the blu parameter with its value using a regex, but I'm unsure on how safe that is.

How would you solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring will skip over anything inside quotes in the SQL (see the `skipCommentsAndQuotes()` method of `NamedParameterUtils`), on the basis that anything inside quotes shouldn't be touched.

That makes sense in this context - you would want the prepared statement to say

```
functionThatTakesAText(?)
```

rather than

```
functionThatTakesAText('?')
```

Try removing the quotes there, and the placeholder should be substituted correctly.

Comment: "see the skipCommentsAndQuotes() method of NamedParameterUtils" I can't find it in the documentation*

*- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterUtils.html

Comment: @awregan: It's not in the documentation, it's in the source code.